# Variables not updating in function in node js in post route

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to make an online Salon booking system, I am trying to make it such that, booking is not made if the salon (to which booking is being made) already has booking for that day and the user who is making the booking does not already have a booking for the same day (I have not considered booking time yet, I am just considering booking date). Below is my booking route :

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var salon = require("../models/salon");
var comment = require("../models/comment");
var booking = require("../models/booking");
var middleware = require("../middleware/index.js");
var flash = require("connect-flash");

router.get("/booking", middleware.canMakeBooking, function (req, res) {
    res.render("booking/new.ejs");
});

router.post("/booking", middleware.canMakeBooking, function (req, res) {
    var salonname = req.body.salonname;
    var date = req.body.date;
    var time = req.body.time;
    var bookingdate = new Date(date);
    var currdate = new Date();
    var client = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    }
    var a = 1;
    var b = 1;

    if (bookingdate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) >= currdate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) {
        salon.findOne({ name: salonname }, function (err, foundsalon) {
            if (!foundsalon) {
                req.flash("error", "no such salon");
                res.redirect("back");
            }
            else {
                var newbooking = { salonName: salonname, date: date, client: client, madeon: Date.now() };

                booking.find().where("client.id").equals(req.user._id).exec(function (err, founduserbooking) {
                    founduserbooking.forEach(function (founduserbooking) {
                        var bookeddate = founduserbooking.date;
                        var alreadybookeddate = new Date(bookeddate);

                        if (alreadybookeddate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) === bookingdate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) {

                            a = 0;

                        }
                    })

                })

                booking.find().where("salonName").equals(salonname).exec(function (err, foundsalonbooking) {

                    foundsalonbooking.forEach(function (foundsalonbooking) {
                        var bookeddate = foundsalonbooking.date;
                        var alreadybookeddate = new Date(bookeddate);

                        if (alreadybookeddate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) === bookingdate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) {
                            b = 0;
                        }
                    })

                })

                if (a === 0) {
                    req.flash("error", "you have already made a booking for this day");
                    res.redirect("/salons");
                }
                else if (b === 0) {
                    req.flash("error", "a booking for this day is already made by someone at this salon");
                    res.redirect("/salons");
                }
                else {
                    booking.create(newbooking, function (err, newlyCreated) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        else {
                            req.flash("success", "booking done!");
                            res.redirect("/salons");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        req.flash("error", "please select a valid date!");
        res.redirect("back");
    }
});

router.delete("/booking/:id", middleware.canMakeBooking, function (req, res) {
    booking.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, updatedbooking) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            req.flash("booking deleted")
            res.redirect("back");
        }
    });
});
```

I am able to create a booking and delete a booking, but the two conditions (checking if salon already has a booking for the date booking is being made & the person making the booking, already has a booking for the same date) are not being met.

I did not include req.flash and res.redirect inside the conditions where conflicting booking is found as by doing so, I am getting the error, "Cannot set headers after they are sent to client"

I think the problem is due to asynchronous nature of node js. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Potentially related, but you're using `a` and `b` as some sort of flag in the `/booking` route handler and setting them inside async callbacks, but checking them *outside* of those callbacks: the code outside of the callbacks will (essentially always) run before any DB calls have completed. I'd recommend taking a step back and figuring out some async programming basics *first* then return to this. I'd also recommend breaking up chunks of functionality into smaller pieces; this is a lot of code to reason about at once.

Answer (score 0):

Using callback functions to receive the query's result isn't a good idea for this case.
You need to use async/await to receive the results and do the logic clearer for debugging.
In your checking code, there are some callback query that makes logic mess up if the result isn't received before returning the response to the client.